# profiler.sh is missing from Android Studio/Contents/bin

Tags: android, macos, profiler

I want to run [standalone profiler](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile?hl=en#standalone-profilers) but i don't see `profiler.sh` inside `/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/bin/`, am i missing something or `profiler.sh` is deleted on newer Android Studio?

[image]

here's my android studio details:

```
Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1
Build #AI-223.8836.35.2231.10406996, built on June 29, 2023
Runtime version: 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b829.9-10027231 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 12.5
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2048M
Cores: 8
Metal Rendering is ON
Registry:
    external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
    ide.text.editor.with.preview.show.floating.toolbar=false
```

does anyone has a copy or paste the script in `profiler.sh`? so i can try to execute it and run standalone profiler

Answer (score 0):

I've post an issue at [Google issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/296173017) and it is not support to run standalone profiler on macos, so they've updated the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile#standalone-profilers)